# Why do I get a syntax error near my over clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `customers` table with `birthdate::date` and `id::integer` columns.

I get a syntax error (`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "over"`) when I run the following query:

```
select lead(age, 1) - age over (order by age) as diff
  from customers
  join (select id,
               extract(year from age(birthdate))::integer as age
          from customers) as sub
        on customers.id = sub.id
order by age;
```

but not when I adjust the first line to

```
select (-age) + lead(age, 1) over (order by age) as diff
```

I don't understand this behavior. What causes the error?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6.6.

Comment: `lead` is a window function which should **have** a `over` clause following it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`over (order by age)` is not a modifier of the complete expression. `lead(...) over(...)` is a single unit, you cannot put random stuff in between. If you want to put the `- age` part later in the expression, you can, you just have to move it back further than what you tried:

```
select lead(age, 1) over (order by age) - age as diff
```

Comment: . . Congratulations on hitting 100k!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use a subquery for this?

```
select lead(age) over (order by age) as diff - age 
from (select c.*, extract(year from age(birthdate))::integer as age
      from customers
     ) c
order by age;
```

I wouldn't be surprised if you wanted a `partition by` as well.